# fragment animation using objectanimator on pre-honey

Tags: android, animation, fragment, objectanimator

I want to use property animation on my app instead of using tween animation on fragment

Right now, I use NineOldAndroids for normal property animation in my app and it works perfectly.

However, I cannot find the way to integrate this NineOldAndroid with support fragment.

Are there any way to animate fragment with property animation on pre-3.0?

Thanks.

Comment: On NineOldAndroids: it can't be done as per told by NineOldAndroids creator himself.

See:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/issues/43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [library](https://github.com/kedzie/Support_v4_NineOldAndroids#fragment).

It integrates support library from Google with NineOldAndroid.